# How to convert a hash string to an integer in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get a hash of a decimal value and convert it to an integer. But the query results in the following error:

`Numeric value 'b902cc4550838229a710bfec4c38cbc7eb11082367a409df9135e7f007a96bda' is not recognized`

```
SELECT (CAST(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ABS(12.5)), 256) AS INTEGER) % 100) AS temp_value
```

What is the correct way to convert a hash string to an integer in Snowflake?
I can not use any user defined functions. And have to go with Snowflake native functions.

Answer (score 0):

The hash value contains alphabetic character so it will throw an error

```js
SELECT --(CAST(
sha2(
TO_VARCHAR(
  ABS(12.5)), 256)-- AS INTEGER) % 100) 
  AS temp_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the hex value from the hash encoding to be int.

I've not been able to find a function built into Snowflake that does this, but if you have a look in the following link, it will explain how to create a javascript function to do the conversion for you:
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/faq-does-snowflake-have-a-hex-to-int-type-function

If you use the function in the link, then your code becomes something like this:

```
SELECT (CAST(js_hextoint(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ABS(12.5)), 256)) AS INTEGER) % 100) AS temp_value
```

I've not been able to test the above code I'm afraid, so there may be a bracket in the wrong place...

Comment: Im'getting the following error: SQL compilation error: Unknown function JS_HEXTOINT

Comment: I can not use any user defined functions. And have to go with Snowflake native functions

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing it without the UDFs. Is there anyone that you can reach out to within your environment to enable these, or to build the one that you will need?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 56 digit hexadecimal number. It's not going to fit into the maximum numeric precision of 38. You could use a floating point number, but that will lose precision.

```
create or replace function CONV(VALUE_IN string, OLD_BASE float, NEW_BASE float)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    // Usage note: Loses precision for very large inputs
    return parseInt(VALUE_IN, Math.floor(OLD_BASE).toString(Math.floor(NEW_BASE)));
$$;

select conv('b902cc4550838229a710bfec4c38cbc7eb11082367a409df9135e7f007a96bda', 16, 10);

--Returns 8.368282050700398e+76
```

Answer (score 0):

For hex to integer, check [Does snowflake have a ‘hex’ to ‘int’ type native function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71919021/132438). My guess is that most people checking this question (1k views) are looking for that.

But this specific question wants to convert a sha2 digest to integer for comparison purposes. My advice for that specific question is "don't".

That's because the hex string in the question represent the integer `83682820507003986697271120393377917644380327831689630185856829040117055843290`, which is too much to handle even by Java's BigInteger.

Instead, just compare strings/binary to check if the values match or not.