# Does snowflake have a ‘hex’ to ‘int’ type native function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This FAQ answer says that Snowflake doesn't have a native way to convert from hex to int, and suggests a JS alternative:

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/faq-does-snowflake-have-a-hex-to-int-type-function

But is there a way to convert from hex to bin with pure SQL in Snowflake?

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ answer is wrong (we are going to fix it soon), as there is a native way to convert hex to int in Snowflake:

```sql
select to_number('fff','XXX');
-- 4095
```

Note that `to_number` needs to have an hexadecimal format string of at least the length of the hexadecimal input. It can be longer too for safety:

```sql
select to_number('fff','XXXXXXXXXXX');
-- 4095
```

Or you can construct the format string out of the length of the input hex string:

```sql
select to_number(h, repeat('X', length(h)))
from (
  select 'fff' h
);
-- 4095
```

```sql
select to_number(h, repeat('X', length(h)))
from (
  select 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' h
);
-- 21267647932558653966460912964485513215
```